# How to calculate mean for a selected range?(pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like

```
Date           Volume

9/23/2019      50
9/24/2019      234
9/25/2019      23124
9/26/2019      23412
9/27/2019      21213
9/30/2019      23241
10/1/2019      231323
10/2/2019      2312
10/3/2019      23213
10/4/2019      421020
10/7/2019      3212
10/8/2019      23122



import pandas as pd
i = input('enter credentials')
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
```

I want to calculate the mean on two conditions:

if the input i is m, then it should calculate the mean of the month and display the result by month, if the input i is w, it should calculate the mean of the week and display the result by week.

There can be more dataframes, a week has 5 days and a month has 20 days in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent showed us the output but by the description, you can try passing the input into this function (extendable):

First convert the date to an actual datetime col:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then :

```
def myinp(i,dataframe,datecol):
    freq_d = {'m':'m','w':'W'}
    return dataframe.groupby(dataframe[datecol]
          .dt.strftime(f"%{freq_d.get(i)}").rename(i)).mean()
```

---

```
print("By m: \n",myinp('m',df,'Date'))
print("---------------------------")
print("By w: \n",myinp('w',df,'Date'))
```

---

```
By m: 
            Volume
m                
09   15212.333333
10  117367.000000
---------------------------
By w: 
       Volume
w           
38   13606.6
39  140221.8
40   13167.0
```

Comment: What would be the same for the range minimum and maximum?

Comment: @AtomStore What do you mean, Sorry I did not get your comment

Comment: the mean is correct, i want to calculate the range of minimum and maximum values in the same case like [minimum,maximum]

Comment: @AtomStore you mean if you replace `.mean()` by `agg(['min','max','mean'])`  in `myinp` ?

Comment: I want the volume as [min,max]